# Pulling GPIO pin to ground

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2

I am trying to use a Pi for a remote power switch for a computer. The way the computer's power switch is configured is that it has a "Power" lead which is 3.3v, and a ground. to turn the computer on, the "Power" lead is simply shorted to the ground lead.

I am trying to accomplish this functionality without using a relay, so Ideally I would like to connect the power lead from the computer to a GPIO pin, and via a python script, pull the GPIO pin to ground, to create the short needed for powering on the computer.

Other solutions are accomplished using interfacing hardware such as another circuit or relay, I would like to simply bring a GPIO pin to ground.

Is this possible with GPIO? Or will I need a relay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to simply bring a GPIO pin to ground

The GPIO itself can be pulled to ground externally by whatever it is attached to, of course, but if you are suggesting you attach a live lead to the GPIO and then send that to ground internally, you cannot.

Note that anything you do attach to a GPIO should not exceed 3.3V or you will bork your pi.  Also, do not set a pin as an output and connect it to ground with no resistance.